# chrome: changes in sources/overrides are not applied?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, console

I've set up the local *Overrides* under the *sources* Tab in Chrome, added `console.logs` in one of the `js` and put some breakpoints after them. After refreshing the page it stops at the breakpoints, but when I go to the *Console* tab, I don't see anything.

On the *Overrides* tab I see a small notification at the file icon, saying `'Linked to source map ...'`, so I suppose that I did everything good, what do I still miss then?

I also tried to create some dummy variables, like `const a=2;` and put the breakpoint after, but on the Local Scope I don't see it.

Any advice is appreciated,

Mat